# Why do we need to add reference to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to all the calling projects if, ODAC is not installed?

Tags: .net, oracle

I am using oracle managedDataAccess provider in my project. I have installed Oracle.ManageddataAccess from nugetPackageManager to that project. I have not installed ODAC separately in my system.

While running it is throwing "**Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed**" Exception. if Oracle.managedDataAccess is not referenced in the calling project as well.

Why do we need to add Oracle.managedDataAccess reference to all the calling projects also ?
Why is just referencing it to the project in which we are actually using it, not working ?

Is there any other way to use managedDataAccess provider, other than installing ODAC or adding Oracle.ManageddataAccess to all the calling projects ?

```
public class ManagedOracleConnectionProperties : Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.AdoDotNetConnectionProperties
{
    public ManagedOracleConnectionProperties()
        : base("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client")
    {
        LocalReset();
    }
    public override void Reset()
    {
        base.Reset();
        LocalReset();
    }
}
```

It is throwing exception here in ("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"). what i meant was I am using this code in say project 'A' and manageddataaccess reference is present in this project. But if I am calling this project('A') from Say Project 'B' I have to refer manageddataaccess to Project 'B' separately otherwise it is throwing this exception.

Comment: In general you need to add reference for any class/namespace you like to in your project, this is nothing special with Oracle. According to the error message you are not using the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` namespace but something different. Please show us your code.

Comment: public ManagedOracleConnectionProperties()
            : base("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client")
        {
            LocalReset();
        }                                                                                                           It is throwing exception here in ("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"). what i meant was I am using this code in say project 'A' and manageddataaccess reference is present in this project. But if I am calling this project('A') from Say Project 'B' I have to refer manageddataaccess  to Project 'B' separately otherwise it is throwing this exception.